# Как защитить роуты от массовых запросов

Tags: php, laravel, ddos

Собственно вопрос в названии темы как защитить маршруты от массовых запросов например больше 50 с одного ip в секунду. Этим нужно заниматься на уровне приложения, или решения должны быть на уровне хостинга типа защита от DDoS атак ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотря какой DDoS. Чтобы просто ограничить наглых пользователей (клиенты, которые стучатся чаще, чем это мы планировали), можно использовать middleware `throttle` (`\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests`)

```
// максимум 60 запросов в 1 минуту
Route::middleware('throttle:60,1')->group(function(){
    // routes
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#rate-limiting

Comment: Да супер, спасибо, тут речь и шла наверное скорее о наглых юзерах.

Comment: Кстати этот подход только для api или для web роутов тоже?

Comment: @Pavel, вроде в любом месте его можно использовать. Посмотри его код)